# Square root for "united" in Pearl Jam "REARVIEWMIRROR" album art?

Tags: lyrics, artwork

Does anyone know why, in the CD booklet for Pearl Jam's second album, *Vs.*, on the lyrics page for the song "REARVIEWMIRROR", the word "united" appears to be replaced with a square-root symbol (`√`)?

Here is an image from [pjcollectors.com](http://www.pjcollectors.com/detail.asp?id=319):

[image]

The full lyric shown above is

> head @ your feet
>   fool to your crown
>   fist on my plate
>   swallowed it down
>   enmity gaged
>   √ *[united]* by FEAR
>   tried to endure
>   what i could not
>   FORGIVE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In live versions of the song, Vedder has sung the lyric "Divided by fear."

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oz6S3X0NGtU) is a live version of Rearviewmirror from Pearl Jam's YouTube channel with the alternate lyric.

The symbol in the lyric sheet was probably intended to be the long division symbol, for "divided."

Comment: I wonder if this means he recorded "united" first, but soon afterward he began vacillating on the lyric and meaning (I recall hearing this was a difficult time for the band) just in time to change the art booklet.